# C# Subir numeros en NumericUpDown y sacar un List en un TextBox

Tags: c#

Tengo un NumericUpDown y necesito que cada vez que cambie el valor, muestre en unos textbox una List que ya tengo predefinida. Tengo este código en el numericUpDownClientes_ValueChanged, pero me da excepción de System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException. 


Gracias!!

```
private void numericUpDownClientes_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (numericUpDownClientes.Value == 0)
        {
            tsbGuardar.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (numericUpDownClientes.Value == 1)
        {
            tsbGuardar.Enabled = false;
            txtNombreClientes.Text = listClientes[0].getNombre();
            txtApellidosClientes.Text = listClientes[0].getApellidos();
            mtxtFechaClientes.Text = listClientes[0].getFecha();
            mtxtNifClientes.Text = listClientes[0].getNif();
            txtDireccionClientes.Text = listClientes[0].getDireccion();
            mtxtCodPostClientes.Text = listClientes[0].getCodigoPost().ToString();
        }
    }
```

tsbGuardar es un botón.

Las que empiezan por Txt son TextBox y las que empiezan por mtxt son MaskedTextBox.

La lista es de objetos de una clase Cliente, en la que tengo definidos los constructores y los setters y getters.

```
Cliente c1 = new Cliente(1, "Pepe", "Lopez Ruiz", "21/05/1997", "65230147-
J", "C/Mayor 23", 2657);
    Cliente c2 = new Cliente(2, "Juan", "Fernandez Polo", "07/11/2000", 
"09086644-W", "C/Picasso 3", 28813);
    Cliente c3 = new Cliente(3, "Carmen", "Cuenca Olmo", "18/10/1996", 
"463017527-M", "C/Aves 25", 24103);
    Cliente c4 = new Cliente(4, "Ana", "Ruiz Dominguez", "01/01/1967", 
"68423671-T", "Avda. Constitucion 83", 26681);
    Cliente c5 = new Cliente(5, "Pedro", "Gomez Hurtado", "09/03/1989", 
"53014895-P", "C/Alameda 79", 28624);

    private bool tsbGuardarClick = false;

    private void valoresArray()
    {
        listClientes.Add(c1);
        listClientes.Add(c2);
        listClientes.Add(c3);
        listClientes.Add(c4);
        listClientes.Add(c5);
    }
```

Comment: Usa un punto de interrupción y mira si por ejemplo `listClientes[0].getNombre()` tiene datos. Además, usa `try/catch` para manejar las excepciones. Usa StackTrace para obtener la línea que arroja la excepción.

Comment: El valor que tiene es GestionPedidos.Form1, Text: Gestion Pedidos. Y si utilizo un bloque try/catch nunca llego a introducir los datos en los Textbox. Lo que necesito es poder quitar arreglar esa excepción

Comment: podes confirmar que listClientes[0] no esta vacio? hiciste un debug para confirmarlo? porque obviamente el error es ese.

Comment: Acabo de comprobarlo en debug y pone que está vacío :(

Answer (score 0):

Como primer paso debieras controlar la excepción que mencionas **System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException** , aqui te dejo un link para que sepas en que consiste la excepción [system.argumentoutofrangeexception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

Como segundo paso en el metodo valuechanged que tu declarastes el segundo **if** deberias ser reemplazado por **else if** , si cumple la 1era condicion realiza lo codificado pero si no cumple la condicion deberia proceder a verificar la 2 condicion con **else if**.

```
private void numericUpDownClientes_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
       if (numericUpDownClientes.Value == 0)
       {
        tsbGuardar.Enabled = false;
       }  
       else if (numericUpDownClientes.Value == 1)
       {
        tsbGuardar.Enabled = false;
        txtNombreClientes.Text = listClientes[0].getNombre();
        txtApellidosClientes.Text = listClientes[0].getApellidos();
        mtxtFechaClientes.Text = listClientes[0].getFecha();
        mtxtNifClientes.Text = listClientes[0].getNif();
        txtDireccionClientes.Text = listClientes[0].getDireccion();
        mtxtCodPostClientes.Text = listClientes[0].getCodigoPost().ToString();
       }
   }catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
    {   
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Y por ultimo poner un punto de interrupción al realizar el llenado de la información para saber en que linea se esta cayendo tu método y tengas la idea del motivo.

Saludos.